# user assigning non-repeating values in a numerical list

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm creating an output ordering function.  The user needs the ability to change the order frequently on the fly (it's used to order pick lists for our order pickers).  I have created a Windows Form, but i need to do some validation on it. The validation itself is simple... the numbers have to be in order and can't repeat. If they repeat, the SQL report bombs out...  I'd also like to validate not skipping any values, but that's not really necessary.

is there a better way than:

```
if NumericUpDown1.value = NumericUpDown2.value then
    error goes here
end if 
if NumericUpDown1.value = NumericUpDown3.value then
    error goes here
end if 
if NumericUpDown1.value = NumericUpDown4.value then
    error goes here
end if ...
```

there is a large list, and this would be thousands of lines of code.  I know there has got to be a simple solution. It's not coming to me, and i've been stuck on it for a couple of days. (yea I know i probably could have just done it already)

Comment: Put the controls in a collection (either manually or by querying the form's controls for that particular type) and check for duplicates by grouping them on `value`.

Comment: Create an array of `NumericUpDownN.value`'s and sort it, and iterate over array to find 2 equal i, i+1 values. Not sure if VB supports linq, Even if not it will not be too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Serg said, put the values into an array and use Linq to group by the values. Then find any duplicates.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim numericList = New Decimal() {
            NumericUpDown1.Value,
            NumericUpDown2.Value,
            NumericUpDown3.Value,
            NumericUpDown4.Value,
            NumericUpDown5.Value
        }

    Dim duplicatesExist = numericList _
        .GroupBy(Function(n) n) _
        .Any(Function(g) g.Count() > 1)

    If duplicatesExist Then
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicates exist")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Duplicates")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: much appreciated. I hate it when the answer is so obvious, but it just doesn't come to you.... I am in a position where i have no support or anyone to bounce ideas off of.

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If it is, please accept my answer. If you need supports or ideas, you can create a new topic in this site.